# TFS 2015 Web Access getting stuck when I click on build definition

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, tfs-2015

I am seeing lot latency issues and the TFS operations and the entire browser are getting stuck when I clicked on build definition / build steps:

[image]

I have restarted IIS multiple times but no luck. When I access the TFS URL through chrome, I am not seeing anything but while accessing through IE I am seeing

> **XXXX is not responding due to long-running script**(stop script bottom of the window).

When I Clicked on it, The page started working and able to do the operations on TFS Web.

Can you please let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you use Chrome or Edge? Try to press F12 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide), and refresh your page, to see whether there is useful information.

Comment: Yes. I have the same issue use Chrome or Edge.(Tried F12/refresh page etc.. but no luck)

Comment: Did you find any useful information in `Network` when you tried F12?

Comment: I didn't see any information when I used F12.

Comment: Cece, Could you please let me know any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Which agent version is installed?
In the past i had like same issues with an old agent.

Also sometimes it really depends on the browser - there are some actions which only can be done in IE / Edge, others only in FF.

Comment: The TFS current AgentVersion is 1.95.3

Comment: Is there any reason for that version? Actually there is agent v 2.131. Think you should try to add a new agent version - just register it to your TFS, you don´t need to kill the older ones.

Comment: Currently, I am using TFS 2015 update 3. So, I am using latest AgentVersion 1.95.3.   Also, I tried different browser but I have been facing same issue.

Comment: Chizzo, Can you please let me know if you have any update on this?

Comment: Sorry, no update for that. What we have noticed is that sometimes it stucks when there is too much ouput. In our case it could be the build has ended, but the console is rolling some information from buildsteps.